# C Structs: Problem Initializing? Valgrind Errors

Tags: c, struct, valgrind

Coding in C:

```
typedef struct {
   char *string;
   int one;
   int two;
} Example;
```

... elsewhere:

```
Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example*));
new->string = strdup(otherstring); //no problem here
new->one = 5; //valgrind says that there is an invalid write of size 4.
```

My program runs fine, I just can't make valgrind happy. And that probably means I will have some other error elsewhere.

I guess I don't have to declare a pointer to the structure, (i.e., I could call "Example new" instead), but I'm stuck finding out how to allocate memory on the heap because I will need to access "new" from other parts of the program.

Am I making a mistake in the above few lines? Or is my error likely to be somewhere else? This is the first memory error that valgrind reports.

EDIT: accidentally had int *s instead of ints in my struct. Fixed.

Comment: Perhaps you need `int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int)); *pi = 5; new->one = pi;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see various problems here. First of all, this:

```
Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example*));
```

doesn't allocate the right amount of memory (and you don't need the cast). You want this:

```
Example *new = malloc(sizeof(Example));
```

Then, you say this:

```
new->one = 5;
```

and that's assigning an `int` to an `int*`; that's not a good idea and valgrind rightly complains about it. If your `struct` is properly declared, then you want this:

```
new->one = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* The other malloc doesn't allocate this, you have to. */
*(new->one) = 5;
```

I suspect (as you say that everything works) that you really mean to declare your `struct` like this:

```
typedef struct {
   char *string;
   int one;
   int *two;
} Example;
```

but there isn't enough information to be certain. Then you probably still have similar issues with `new->two`.

Answer (score 0):

Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example*));

Should be:

Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example);

You have to allocate the whole struct not just a reference to it.  Sometimes the program runs just because you get lucky.

Comment: Explicit cast, not required in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Just to clarify: Don't use a * inside the sizeof()

Comment: Bob you meant `Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example));`??

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (just cut, paste, and run):

```
Example *new = (Example *)malloc(sizeof(Example));  //This is the correct method as pointed out by Bob, otherwise you're allocating only enough space to fit a memory location vs the struct
new->string = strdup(otherstring);  //this is okay
new->one = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*(new->one) = 5; //You want to assign the value 5 to the new->one memory location, not assign new->one pointer the value of 5!!!
```

Comment: But `new->one` would need to be allocated before assigning something to where it points.

Comment: @Joseph: Sir you are absolutely correct! I've corrected my answer and +1 for you!